# Error importing VM to AWS : S3 key does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hyper-v-server-2012-r2, import

I need to import a Gen2 Hyper-V machine to AWS and I'm following the document here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html

All works fine until I use this command to upload the image:

```
aws ec2 import-image --description "XYZVM" --license-type AWS --disk-containers file://containers.json
```

containers.json file is like this:

```
[
  {
    "Description": "First disk",
    "Format": "vhdx",
    "UserBucket": {
        "S3Bucket": "xyzvmimport",
        "S3Key": "xyWin10.vhdx"
        }
  },          
  {
    "Description": "Second disk",
    "Format": "vhdx",
    "UserBucket": {
        "S3Bucket": "xyzvmimport",
        "S3Key": "xyWin11.vhdx"
    }
  }
]
```

vhdx files & container.json are on the same folder. I run the command from within the folder as an administrator but I get this error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the ImportImage operation: S3 key does not exist: xyWin10.vhdx
```

I also made sure that the files have full access to "everyone" to make sure it's not a permission issue.

What's happening here? Why is this tool not working?

Comment: The S3 key seems to be referencing a file. Have you triple checked your syntax is correct and that file exists?

Comment: @Tim I quadruple checked it. They're there

Comment: When you say 'vhdx files & container.json are on the same folder', you mean on the folder on your local machine? because the vhdx files need to be uploaded to the S3 bucket.

Comment: If you will not fix the import, you may use as alternative starwind v2v to migrate VM from Hyper-V to AWS - https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter

Answer (score 1):

As Alex Moore suggested in the comment to the original question.

> When you say 'vhdx files & container.json are on the same folder', you mean on the folder on your local machine? because the vhdx files need to be uploaded to the S3 bucket

I was also assuming the ova was from my workstation. Once I uploaded the ova to the bucket and ran the import-image command it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods of configuring the `containers.json` script. The first one is:

1. Specifying the image using an s3 bucket. The json snippet is:

```
[
  {
    "Description": "My Server OVA",
    "Format": "ova",
    "UserBucket": {
        "S3Bucket": "my-import-bucket",
        "S3Key": "vms/my-server-vm.ova"
    }
  }
]
```

2. Specifying the image using the image using a URL in Amazon S3. An example is:

```
[
  {
    "Description": "My Server OVA",
    "Format": "ova",
    "Url": "s3://my-import-bucket/vms/my-server-vm.ova"
  }
]
```

After failing with the first option, I tried the second one, which worked.
The solution's reference can be found [here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html)